# Ionic: border on autocomplete using CSS

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am trying to apply border on autocomplete tag in my ionic code using CSS. So I have this:

```
<div class="list list-inset">
<autocomplete attr-placeholder="type here to search..."></autocomplete>
</div>
```

Then this is my css code

```
<style type="text/css">
autocomplete {
    border: 1px solid #151b54;
}
</style>
```

The challenge is that the border is never applied on the autocomplete. 
Please what could be wrong?

Comment: Which is the autocomplete component that are you using? can you put the link in your question please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `<autocomplete` tag is converted internally into standard HTML, I would add a class to the `<autocomplete` tag, like this:

```
<autocomplete class="autocomplete-with-border" attr-placeholder="..."></autocomplete>
```

And then in the CSS:

```
.autocomplete-with-border input {
    border: 1px solid #151b54;
}
```

Another option would be to surround your `<autocomplete` tag around a `<div class="autocomplete-with-border">`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly which directive are you using, but ... the problem is that the tag `<autocomplete>` is a `directive` that have more html code inside. If you inspect the html running the app in the desktop's browser you can see wich tags there are inside. 
Probably you want to apply the border to the input tag so.. the css could be something like:

```
autocomplete input{
    border: 1px solid #151b54;
}
```